# Writing char with variables

Tags: c

Let us say i have:

```
printf("Hello, my name is %s\n", name_variable);
```

I want to save the string that `printf` produces in a char array, so that I can `write` it somewhere. One solution to do this is to declare a `char` array and then use `strcpy` and `strcat` on it. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do so.

Comment: man sprintf ................

Comment: You cannot save a *nul-terminated* `string` in a `char`, you need a character *array*. You can use `strcpy`, `strcat`, or a loop and a pointer. Your choice. (to save the whole string -- yest `sprintf` as the other comments suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to save the string that printf produces in a char

You mean in a `char` array?

You can use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)

```
  char buffer [50];
  int a=2, b=3;
  snprintf (buffer, 50, "%d + %d = %d", a, b, a+b);
```

Comment: Use snprintf to prevent buffer overflow

Comment: Seconded. `sprintf` is almost as dangerous as `strcpy`.  Always use `snprintf`: `snprintf(buffer, 50, ...`

Comment: From a security perspective, I do not recommend this method whatsoever. Do it well from the beginning: use snprintf() instead. What is the difference? You have to specify the maximum number of bytes that can be copied. This is critical to security and one of the most common security mistakes a software engineer can do.

Comment: @Steve Summit Any particular reason for recommending `snprintf(buffer, 50, ...` vs. `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, ...`?  (The latter, IMO, is less error prone and easier to maintain)

Comment: @chux Only because I didn't want someone taking the advice too much to heart, and next week writing `char *buffer = malloc(50); snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ...` and getting confused.  There's definitely a time to learn about `sizeof(buffer)`, and of course I write it that way too, when applicable, but for a newbie who doesn't even know about `sprintf` yet (let alone `snprintf`), sometimes I favor taking things one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Please look up [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/]

This function is able to store the value in a string

The code goes like thus:

```
char s[1024]; // or some other suitable value

snprintf(s, 1024, "Hello, my name is %s\n", name_variable);

printf("Here it is %s\n", s);
```

Comment: Using `snprintf()` vs `sprintf()` solves one problem (buffer overflow prevention) yet has another: `s` is truncated and used.  Recommend using `snprintf()` and checking its return value.